# How could I change the order of trackbars in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, user-interface, trackbar

By using cvCreateTrackbar(), I create some trackbars, but these trackbars are disordered. And I can't find any function in OpenCV to change the order.

So...How could I change the order of trackbars in OpenCV?

(And forgive my poor English.)

It seems that in my program the order of track bars on the window is not the same as they are in my source code.

In my source code:

Brightness

Contrast

Grey

Grey R Percent

Grey G Percent

Grey B Percent

Temperature

Hue

Saturation

Equalize

And on the window:

Grey G Percent

Contrast

Equalize

Brightness

Grey

Grey G Percent

Grey R Percent

Temperature

Hue

Saturation